# Is there a way to display a specific category which has highest post (if post assigned in multiple category ) in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm posting articles in my Wordpress blog and assigning it to multiple categories (suppose: 3 categories). I want to display only one category which has **highest post**. Is there any way to retrieve the category by post count.

It will be very helpful for me if anyone solve this for me.

Comment: I should think this is possible. Are you modifying a theme or child theme? You would need to modify the index file (for a number of posts) and the single page file (for one). The strategy for both is to obtain the categories, then get a post count for each, sort the categories array by post count descending, and then use the first one. If you take a look at the WP dev docs, you should find these sufficient to do the above, if you break the problem down sufficiently. Give it a go! `:)`

Comment: I am developing a wordpress theme ( not child theme).Basically my knowledge in php quite poor,can you give me the code you describe above,it will be very helpful for me.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It's hard for us to work out what you need if we cannot see what you already have, and send-me-the-code posts tend to be discouraged anyway, since they are too localised. However, if you can edit your post with the theme code you already have, that is a good start. I presume you are starting with a ready-made theme and modifying it?